# Compile Micro Focus Net Express 5.1 Cobol in Powershell

Tags: powershell, cobol

I am hoping someone might be able to help me with writing a COBOL MF Net Express 5.1 compile command in Powershell. I have the command as it was used in the original batch script. I am currently working on reworking this in Powershell as a build script.

```
COBOL.EXE "%%inFile%%" OUTDD NOERRQ NOFLAGQ NOQUERY noALTER noanim nobound checkdiv COMP errlist list() FASTLINK omf"gnt" perform-type"osvs" SCHEDULER TARGET"PENTIUM" noTRUNC vsc2(1) listpath"","%%OUTPUT%%";,;,;
```

My attempt at converting this to Powershell has been like this:

```
$cobolExe = ".\COBOL.EXE"
$expression = "& $cobolExe `"$($inputfile)`" OUTDD NOERRQ NOFLAGQ NOQUERY noALTER noanim nobound checkdiv COMP errlist list() FASTLINK omf`"gnt`" perform-type`"osvs`" SCHEDULER TARGET`"PENTIUM`" noTRUNC vsc2(1) listpath`"`", `"$binPath\`";,;,;"
Invoke-Expression $expression

Invoke-Expression: 
Line |
   1 |  Invoke-Expression $expression
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | At line:1 char:97 + … GQ NOQUERY noALTER noanim nobound checkdiv COMP errlist list() FASTLI … +                                                                ~
An expression was expected after '('.  At line:1
     | char:221 + … NTIUM" noTRUNC vsc2(1) listpath"", "C:\dev\dimensions\test\bin\";,;,; +                                                                     ~
Missing expression after unary operator ','.  At line:1
     | char:223 + … NTIUM" noTRUNC vsc2(1) listpath"", "C:\dev\dimensions\test\bin\";,;,; +                                                                       ~
Missing expression after unary operator ','.
```

I successfully have this working with CBLLINK.EXE, but it does not require as many parameters.

```
$cobolFile = "$Path\cobol.dir"
$cbllinkExe = ".\CBLLINK.EXE"

$expression = "$cbllinkExe -s -o$($outputFile) `"$($inputFile)`" adis adisinit adiskey -u`"$cobolFile`""
Invoke-Expression $expression
```

Anyone who might have any insight and could provide some assistance, I would very much appreciate it. Please let me know if I can provide anything else?

Comment: Calling external exe's/cmd's via PowerShell requires specific attention. IT is a well-documented thing. See these details from Microsoft and others: --- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx#The_Call_Operator_amp --- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx --- and --- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters, there are more like these.

Comment: Thank you! CMD /C worked for what I needed.

Comment: No worries, I'll move this comment to the answer section so you can mark it as your accepted answer for the benefit of others who may run into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling external exe's/cmd's via PowerShell requires specific attention. It is a well-documented thing.

See these details from Microsoft and others: ---

> [PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx#The_Call_Operator_amp)
>
> 5. The Call Operator &

```
# Example:
& 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' "c:\videos\my home video.avi" /fullscreen
```

> Things can get tricky when an external command has a lot of parameters
>   or there are spaces in the arguments or paths!
>
> With spaces you have to nest Quotation marks and the result it is not
>   always clear!
>
> In this case it is better to separate everything like so:

```
$CMD = 'SuperApp.exe'
$arg1 = 'filename1'
$arg2 = '-someswitch'
$arg3 = 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt'
$arg4 = '-yetanotherswitch'

& $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4

# or same like that:
$AllArgs = @('filename1', '-someswitch', 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt', '-yetanotherswitch')
& 'SuperApp.exe' $AllArgs
```

> 6. cmd /c - Using the old cmd shell
>      ** This method should no longer be used with V3
>
> Why: Bypasses PowerShell and runs the command from a cmd shell. Often
>   times used with a DIR which runs faster in the cmd shell than in
>   PowerShell (NOTE: This was an issue with PowerShell v2 and its use of
>   .Net 2.0, this is not an issue with V3).
>
> Details: Opens a CMD prompt from within powershell and then executes
>   the command and returns the text of that command. The /c tells CMD
>   that it should terminate after the command has completed. There is
>   little to no reason to use this with V3.

```
# Example:
#runs DIR from a cmd shell, DIR in PowerShell is an alias to GCI. This will return the directory listing as a string but returns much faster than a GCI
cmd /c dir c:\windows
```

> [Using Windows PowerShell to run old command line tools (and their
>   weirdest parameters)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters)
>
> Solution 2A: Use CMD /C
>
> As with the first problem, you can run CMD.EXE itself and pass your
>   command and its parameters in quotes. Efficiency aside, this will work
>   fine, since PowerShell will not try to parse the string in quotes.

```
CMD.EXE /C "ICACLS.EXE C:TEST /GRANT USERS:(F)"

<#
# Results

processed file: C:TEST
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
#>
```

..there are more like these.